# Simple pregmatch

Tags: powershell, preg-match

I have got $a = 5816.3.big.jpg;

I want to see in $a all symbols before first "."

What pregmatch can do it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$a = "5816.3.big.jpg"
$a.split(".")[0]
5816
```

Sorry about that. You wanted regex.

```
$a = "5816.3.big.jpg"
[regex]::matches($a,"^([^\.]+)\.")[0].groups[1].value
5816
```

Or:

```
$a = "5816.3.big.jpg"
[void]($a -match "^([^\.]+)\.")
$matches[1]
5816
```

Comment: Looks good, but does not work in powershell. I don't know right syntax for split. I have got some code into it: `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path .\123;
 foreach ($file in $files)
{

$a = $file.name;
$a -split "[.]";
echo $a;
}` result of a is 4 words, how to work only with first?

Comment: That's what the array slicing does. Split give you and array. The [0] give you the first element of that array. Try this:$files = Get-ChildItem -Path .\123; foreach ($file in $files) {($file.name).split(".")[0]}

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
PS > "5816.3.big.jpg" -replace '\..+$'
5816

PS > Get-ChildItem -Path .\123 | Foreach-Object { $_.Name -replace '\..+$' }
```